# save file google cloud storage with cram and tag

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have a task that required from me to test:

1. create a file on me local machine
2. upload to google cloud storage as set of cram file, that identified by name tag.
3. trigger function that analysis process

after some digging i found a piece of code that show how to get the set of the bucket, but i do not understand how to upload the file that it would be cram format :(

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('gs://hmf-dr-123')
manifest_json =  bucket.get_blob('manifest.json')
data = json.loads(manifest_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of get_bucket(), it should be the bucket name only(without `gs://`).

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('hmf-dr-123')
manifest_json =  bucket.get_blob('manifest.json')
data = json.loads(manifest_json)
```